# Error when installing ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, npm, terminal, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

There comes an error when installing ng-bootstrap to my Angular-CLI(11.0.4).
When

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

And my log file

```
[error] Error: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: front@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@11.0.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~11.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"11.1.1" from @angular/localize@11.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peer @angular/localize@"^11.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/damika/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/damika/.npm/_logs/2021-02-02T16_41_53_338Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
    at Object.installPackage (/home/damika/Desktop/CACHE/School/Front/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/install-package.js:40:15)
    at AddCommand.run (/home/damika/Desktop/CACHE/School/Front/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/add-impl.js:149:31)
    at async AddCommand.validateAndRun (/home/damika/Desktop/CACHE/School/Front/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:139:28)
    at async Object.runCommand (/home/damika/Desktop/CACHE/School/Front/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:204:24)
    at async default_1 (/home/damika/Desktop/CACHE/School/Front/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:80:31)
```

Error in terminal

```
An unhandled exception occurred: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: front@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@11.0.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~11.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"11.1.1" from @angular/localize@11.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peer @angular/localize@"^11.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/damika/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/damika/.npm/_logs/2021-02-02T16_38_17_817Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
See "/tmp/ng-qJ50sG/angular-errors.log" for further details.
(base) damika@damiboy:~/Desktop/CACHE/School/Front/src/app$ ng update
The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 28 dependencies.
    Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon: aborted
    We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:
    
      Name                               Version                  Command to update
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/cli                       11.0.7 -> 11.1.2         ng update @angular/cli
      @angular/core                      11.0.9 -> 11.1.1         ng update @angular/core
    
    There might be additional packages which don't provide 'ng update' capabilities that are outdated.
    You can update the additional packages by running the update command of your package manager.
(base) damika@damiboy:~/Desktop/CACHE/School/Front/src/app$ ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap 
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
An unhandled exception occurred: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: front@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@11.0.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~11.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"11.1.1" from @angular/localize@11.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peer @angular/localize@"^11.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/damika/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/damika/.npm/_logs/2021-02-02T16_41_53_338Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
See "/tmp/ng-ySkXlt/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Anyone can help me; thanks for the help :)

Comment: I just did an upgrade before trying again.. `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use the `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` and it will solve your problem

Comment: `npm i @angular/localize`, ng-bootstrap need it

Answer (score 54):

Try using this

`npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`

this allows for installing legacy packages

If you are a Linux user. try adding `sudo` at the beginning of your command

Answer (score 15):

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

You just have to update angular, it works for me, but you'll need to commit before, then just do again, it's not the same "npm i" to "ng add" the second has schematics,so that makes easier installation

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Comment: It is possible to run into dirty/not clean repository problems this way, I believe

Comment: Nice! This worked

Answer (score 9):

Execute the following command. This was the solution to my problem.

**npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps**

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will help someone

```
npm i  --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps
```

it solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

Run below commands sequentially to update angular CLI and install ng-bootstrap in your project.

`ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

`npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with `@angular-eslint/schematics` recently. I solved it by installing the package with npm, then installing the deps with ng:

```
npm install @angular-eslint/schematics --legacy-peer-deps
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved most dependencies nightmares issues by doing the following:

- npm install
- check the name of the package which is causing problems, because of wrong (obsolete) version
- npm uninstall  --legacy-peer-deps
- npm install

This should install the compatible version and the corresponding line in package.json should be update with the right version.

Repeat this for all the packages causing an ERR or a WARN.

If everything goes right at the end you should be able to launch npm install without having any issue.

I followed this while upgrading from Angular 14 to Angular 16 and it worked.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Add this command and your problem will solved:
`npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Angular 16.2.5. What works for me is using `npm i bootstrap` in the project CLI. Then add the bootstrap CSS to your CSS file by linking it to the bootstrap CSS file.

Answer (score -1):

npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@next , would work just fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.