# Error while installing ng-bootstrap in angular v-13

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, installation, ng-bootstrap, angular13

Throwing the below error while trying to install ng-bootstrap in angular version 13

Error :
[image]

These are the other details respective to the node, npm and os

> Angular CLI: 13.0.2, Node: 16.13.0, Package Manager: npm 8.1.0, OS:
> darwin x64

Found a similar question here
[Error when installing ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014183/error-when-installing-ng-add-ng-bootstrap-ng-bootstrap)
and tried to use the solution given in the answers, but doesn't work for me.

Much appreciate any help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Throws this -- Unknown option: '--legacy-peer-deps'.

Comment: And this? ```ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue for me

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

which means it allows installing legacy packages.

Answer (score 0):

use this `cmd` first: **`npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`** and close the `cmd` and again restart your cmd and run `cmd`: **`ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force`**
.It works and check in `angular.json` file, you will find your `ng bootstrap` will install.