# Error installing Bootstrap (Ngb Module) in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, bootstrap-5

I want to install Ngb in Angular.
I use n Node.js version v19.1.0. I already tried --force and --legacy-pear-drops. Also i tried reinstalling Node.js.

The log:
`` `npm ERR! code ERESOLVE ``
`npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve`
`npm ERR!`
`npm ERR! While resolving: markb@0.0.0`
`npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@14.2.2`
`npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core`
`npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"14.2.2" from @angular/animations@14.2.2`
`npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations`
`npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"14.2.2" from @angular/platform-browser@14.2.2`
`npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser`
`npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"14.2.2" from @angular/forms@14.2.2`
`npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms`
`npm ERR!         @angular/forms@"^14.1.0" from the root project`
`npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)`
`npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^14.1.0" from the root project`
`npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"14.2.2" from @angular/common@14.2.2`
`npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common`
`npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"14.2.2" from @angular/forms@14.2.2`
`npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms`
`npm ERR!       @angular/forms@"^14.1.0" from the root project`
`npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"14.2.2" from @angular/platform-browser@14.2.2`
`npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser`
`npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"14.2.2" from @angular/forms@14.2.2`
`npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms`
`npm ERR!         @angular/forms@"^14.1.0" from the root project`
`npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)`
`npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)`
`npm ERR!   6 more (@angular/compiler, @angular/forms, ...)`
`npm ERR!`
`npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:`
`npm ERR! @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"13.1.1" from the root project`
`npm ERR!`
`npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@14.2.12`
`npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core`
`npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"14.2.12" from @angular/forms@14.2.12`
`npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms`
`npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^14.1.0" from the root project`
`npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@"^14.1.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@13.1.1`
`npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
`npm ERR!       @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"13.1.1" from the root project`
`npm ERR!`
`npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry`
`npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps`
`npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.`
`npm ERR!`
`npm ERR! See C:\Users\thomas\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.`

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`
`npm ERR!     C:\Users\thomas\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-24T10_07_23_103Z-debug-0.log`
`` × Packages installation failed, see above.` ``

I expected installs Bootstrap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First try `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`. Maybe you must also run `npm audit fix`  See also [angular bootstrap is giving error on angular 13 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70843376/angular-bootstrap-is-giving-error-on-angular-13-project)

Comment: This also solved my error, thnaks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using Angular CLI for setting up a new project. If you have an Angular ≥ 9 CLI project.

Just run the following:

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

It will install ng-bootstrap for the default application specified in your angular.json. If you have multiple projects and you want to target a specific application, you could specify the --project option

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --project myProject
```

Comment: i know but this does not work...