Angular 10 Upgrade Issue: Module Not Found for '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/util/positioning'
I'm currently upgrading my Angular application from version 8 to version 10. During the build process, I encountered the following error:
ERROR in ./src/app/components/input/typeahead.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/util/positioning'
- **Angular Version**: Upgraded to 10
- **ng-bootstrap Version**: 7.x
- **Issue**: The build process fails with the error above.
Steps Taken:
1. **Verified Installation**: Confirmed that `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` is installed.
2. **Checked Import Paths**: Ensured import paths in `typeahead.ts` are correct.
3. **Version Adjustments**: Tried upgrading and downgrading `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` versions.
4. **Reinstalled Dependencies**: Deleted `node_modules` and reinstalled using `npm install`.

Similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70843376/angular-bootstrap-is-giving-error-on-angular-13-project

If I check the source code of ng-bootstrap, I see that typeahead.ts is in /typeahead instead of util.
Try to import from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead instead.
