# failed to install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap in angular project (angular/cli version:15.0.0)

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

i didnt understand why i can't install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap module, you think ng-bootstrap didn't support angular 15.0.0 or something else ??
it worked at my project at version older
i tried this command before npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps , it installed but per example i wanted  modal ng-bootstrap in my project but it didn't work

[image: thats what i got]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when installing ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014183/error-when-installing-ng-add-ng-bootstrap-ng-bootstrap)

Comment: It's strange the error. say that you're try to install ng-bootstrap@13.1.1 (It's only for Angular 14) (see the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#dependencies)). BTW try install the lastest:" Support for Angular 15 is available with 14.0.0-rc.X via npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@next " (see the `@next`at the end). NOTE: Diferent Angular version need different versions of ng-bootstrap (and bootstrap.css)